# Entry point for a bokeh server

Tags: python, setuptools, bokeh, setup.py

I provide a tool as part of my python package that visualizes a parameter space using bokeh. The normal way to launch it would be:

```
$ bokeh serve --show my_package/tools/my_tool.py
```

Which opens a browser and shows an interactive plot.
However, when I install this package using pip/ PyPI users can not easily access this folder, so I would like to provide an entry point for this in my setup.py.

Package Layout:

```
folder
|
|--- my_package
|     |
|     |- __init__.py
|     |- __main__.py
|     |- some_code.py
|     |
|     +--- tools
|           |
|           +--- my_tool.py
|
+--setup.py
```

In my setup.py I already specify an entry point to my main method:

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = "my_package",
    packages = find_packages(),
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'my_package = my_package.__main__:main'
          ]
    },
    [...],
)
```

However, the only way I found to launch the bokeh server and show the interface was to create another python script like this

```
import os
from subprocess import call

def main():
    p = os.path.realpath(__file__)
    prefix, _ = os.path.split(p)
    bokeh_server_file = os.path.join(prefix, "my_tool.py")
    call(["bokeh", "serve", "--show", bokeh_server_file])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

place it in the `tools` folder and create an entry point for this scripts main method. **shudder** There has to be a better way to do this.

Is it possible to provide this kind of entry point using setuptools or is there another way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you can go the embedded server route which is covered in the [Embedding Bokeh Server as a Library](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-bokeh-server-as-a-library) document. There's a follow up line about using the bokeh server client api following that part of the documentation. It sounds like they're working on more ways to connect to the server in the future as well in the part where they discuss use cases.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I found a way to make it work using the [standalone embed example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.4/examples/howto/server_embed/standalone_embed.py).

Comment: How do you allow a different websocket origin using either of these approaches? Similar to "bokeh serve app_script.py --allow-websocket-origin foo.com:8081" command

Comment: @dnh37 take a look at the linked examples covered in the link I provide. Search for the line `server = Server({'/bkapp': modify_doc}, allow_websocket_origin=["localhost:8000"])`; you basically define it in the `Server` constructor.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on [the answer of @jxramos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42970443/2862719), I modified the [standalone embed example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.4/examples/howto/server_embed/standalone_embed.py) given on the page. By managing the tornado IO loop yourself in the main function you can make your bokeh script behave like a *normal* python script that automatically starts a browser when executed.

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.server.server import Server

def modify_doc(doc):
    """Function that modifies a document."""
    # [...] create a plot
    doc.add_root(plot)
    doc.title = "Test Plot"

def main():
    """Launch the server and connect to it."""
    io_loop = IOLoop.current()
    bokeh_app = Application(FunctionHandler(modify_doc)) # pass the function that assembles your document here.
    server = Server({"/": bokeh_app}, io_loop=io_loop)
    server.start()
    print("Opening Bokeh application on http://localhost:5006/")

    io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    io_loop.start()

main()
```

This script can then be called from the command line

```
$ python my_tool.py
```

and hence be used for an entry point as expected:

```
[...]
entry_points = {
    'console_scripts': [
        'my_package = my_package.tools.my_tool:main'
      ]
},
[...]
```

---

## General Version

The following is a more complete example that I ported over from a Documentation example I wrote. Since Documentation is being phased out, I think it is better suited as part of this answer.

### Local bokeh server with console entry point

To allow a bokeh application to be executed like a *normal* .py file, you need to handle the tornado IOloop in your application, as described [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-bokeh-server-as-a-library). A standalone bokeh application like this can be used to implement a console script entry point in `setup.py`.
However, this requires bokeh version **>= 0.12.4**.

### The bokeh application

Consider the file `local_server.py`:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.server.server import Server


def modify_doc(doc):
    """Add a plotted function to the document.

    Arguments:
        doc: A bokeh document to which elements can be added.
    """
    x_values = range(10)
    y_values = [x ** 2 for x in x_values]
    data_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x_values, y=y_values))
    plot = figure(title="f(x) = x^2",
                  tools="crosshair,pan,reset,save,wheel_zoom",)
    plot.line('x', 'y', source=data_source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)
    doc.add_root(plot)
    doc.title = "Test Plot"


def main():
    """Launch the server and connect to it.
    """
    print("Preparing a bokeh application.")
    io_loop = IOLoop.current()
    bokeh_app = Application(FunctionHandler(modify_doc))

    server = Server({"/": bokeh_app}, io_loop=io_loop)
    server.start()
    print("Opening Bokeh application on http://localhost:5006/")

    io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    io_loop.start()


main()
```

This file can be executed

```
$ python local_server.py
```

which run the server and automatically launch a browser to show the document.

### Entry points and the setup.py

In order to provide a script that can be easily installed and called using the setup.py. Consider the following folder structure:

```
project
├── setup.py
└── my_package
    ├── __init__.py
    └── local_server.py
```

Content of `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = "my_package",
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": ["my_script = my_package.local_server:main"],
    },
)
```

When installing the package using

```
$ python setup.py install
```

you can then use the call

```
$ my_script
```

to launch the bokeh application and automatically start a browser displaying the document.

Comment: Very cool, I'm still looking for background info on the relation of bokeh Application objects to documents, so far it seems to me its a 1:1 relationship. So if I want two views of the same data I need two applications. Does that sound accurate to what you've gathered so far? From the glossary we have "Application: A Bokeh application is a rendered Bokeh document, running in a browser.", and then "Documents: An organizing data structure for Bokeh applications. Documents contain all the Bokeh Models and data needed to render an interactive visualization or application in the browser."

Comment: @jxramos I am confused as well ;) I think nothing is stopping you from using several charts in one document (rendered in one application, I guess?) like in the [heatmap example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/heatmap_chart.html). As long as you use the same underlying data source, changing the data like in the [sliders example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/slider.html) should effect all associated charts. Also [linking plots](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/linking.html#userguide-interaction-linking) seems pretty neat.

Comment: Taking a second look I noticed Server takes a dictionary as an argument, so I checked out the source, which has a helpful comment...
`applications (dict of str: bokeh.application.Application) or bokeh.application.Application:   mapping from URL paths to Application instances, or a single Application to put at the root URL The Application is a factory for Document, with a new Document initialized for each Session. Each application should be identified by a path meant to go in a URL, like "/" or "/foo"`

Comment: How do we allow different origins?  Equivalent to "bokeh serve script.py --allow-websocket-origin foo.com:8081" in the non-standalone version